# Having problems with a KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm new to graphics programming and am having some difficluties with using a KeyListener to move and image left or right. Currently my code does not even register that a key is being pressed. If someone could help me out with just getting it to register this then I can do the rest myself.

Here is the frame code:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FrameMain extends JFrame {

    final JPanel pnlShow;
    PanelHome pnlHome = new PanelHome();
    PanelPlayerInfo pnlPlayerInfo = new PanelPlayerInfo();
    PanelPlay pnlPlay = new PanelPlay(pnlPlayerInfo);
    PanelInstruction pnlInstructions = new PanelInstruction();
    PanelStore pnlStore = new PanelStore();
    PanelHighscores pnlHighscores = new PanelHighscores();
    ControlActionListenter CAL = new ControlActionListenter();

    public FrameMain() {
        pnlShow = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        pnlShow.add(pnlHome, "Home");
        pnlShow.add(pnlPlay, "Play");
        pnlShow.add(pnlInstructions, "Instructions");
        pnlShow.add(pnlStore, "Store");
        pnlShow.add(pnlHighscores, "Highscores");
        pnlShow.add(pnlPlayerInfo, "PlayerInfo");

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("TANKS");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(806, 628);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.add(pnlShow);
        this.addKeyListener(new Move());

        pnlHome.btnExit.addActionListener(CAL);
        pnlHome.btnExit.setActionCommand("Exit");
        pnlHome.btnPlay.addActionListener(CAL);
        pnlHome.btnPlay.setActionCommand("PlayerInfo");
        pnlHome.btnInst.addActionListener(CAL);
        pnlHome.btnInst.setActionCommand("Instructions");
        pnlHome.btnHigh.addActionListener(CAL);
        pnlHome.btnHigh.setActionCommand("Highscores");
        pnlInstructions.btnBack.addActionListener(CAL);
        pnlInstructions.btnBack.setActionCommand("Main");
        pnlPlay.pnlToolbar.btnHome.addActionListener(CAL);
        pnlPlay.pnlToolbar.btnHome.setActionCommand("Main");
        pnlHighscores.btnBack.addActionListener(CAL);
        pnlHighscores.btnBack.setActionCommand("Main");
        pnlPlayerInfo.btnPlay.addActionListener(CAL);
        pnlPlayerInfo.btnPlay.setActionCommand("Play");
        pnlPlayerInfo.btnBack.addActionListener(CAL);
        pnlPlayerInfo.btnBack.setActionCommand("Main");

    }

    class ControlActionListenter implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (pnlShow.getLayout());
            String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

            if (cmd.equals("Main")) {
                cl.show(pnlShow, "Home");
            } else if (cmd.equals("Exit")) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (cmd.equals("Play")) {
                pnlPlay.arpPlayer[0].populateName(pnlPlayerInfo.txtPlayer1.getText());
                pnlPlay.arpPlayer[1].populateName(pnlPlayerInfo.txtPlayer2.getText());
                pnlPlay.pnlPlayer.lblPlayer1.setText(pnlPlay.arpPlayer[0].sPlayer);
                pnlPlay.pnlPlayer.lblPlayer2.setText(pnlPlay.arpPlayer[1].sPlayer);
                cl.show(pnlShow, "Play");
            } else if (cmd.equals("PlayerInfo")) {
                cl.show(pnlShow, "PlayerInfo");
            } else if (cmd.equals("Instructions")) {
                cl.show(pnlShow, "Instructions");
            } else if (cmd.equals("Highscores")) {
                cl.show(pnlShow, "Highscores");
            }
        }
    }

    class Move implements KeyListener {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("rp");
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("rp");
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("rp");
        }
    }
}
```

I have added a keylistener to the frame and made a class that implements this keylistener. Like I said, all I want to do is have the program output something when I hit a key on the keyboard. If I need to show you anything else let me know and I will post it.

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue with KeyListener

Comment: `this.setSize(806, 628);`  Don't do that.  Instead, set a preferred size for the custom content area, add it using layouts to a panel with any other components required, add/set the panel as the content pane, and call `pack()` on the frame.  It will be the minimum size needed to display the components and frame decorations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `KeyListener` to the components you need, not the whole `JFrame`. And make sure they are focused.

Also you may find [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) useful, as an alternative to key listeners.

Comment: I strongly second the Key Bindings recommendation. That's the way to go for this. 1+.

Comment: Thanks for the Key Bindings idea, I will definitely look into that. I am curious though as to why the key listener does not work though. I tried adding to panel that the image is on but that doesn't work either (just changed this.addKeyListener(new Move()) to pnlPlay.adKeyListener(new Move()) ).

Comment: @user1366342 make sure the component is focusable and has focus.

Comment: I think I did this right. I put: 
        pnlPlay.setFocusable(true);
        pnlPlay.requestFocusInWindow();

in the ControlActionListener class where I switch to pnlPlay as the panel that shows.

Comment: @user1366342 it is hard to say without SSCCE - there are many panels in the code above that you don't share. Issues with focus can be tricky. I recommend you look into Key Bindings. Also, note that [requestFocusInWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29) may not be honored.